# Where's the autohide taskbar option in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, fullscreen

I am currently running Windows 10 and I recently ran into an issue. When I go full-screen in programs like Photoshop the taskbar does not autohide.

If I right-click on the taskbar and go into settings:

Lock the taskbar is disabled

Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode is disabled

Automatically hide the taskbar in tablet mode is disabled

If I go into Control Panel and click on taskbar settings I am greeted by the same list of options above. There is no longer an automatically hide the taskbar option.

If I enable Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode then the taskbar automatically hides, but all of the time, not just when a program is in full-screen mode.

What are my options?

Comment: *"When I go full-screen in programs like Photoshop..."* -  To clarify, does that happen for every program that you switch to full-screen?  For example, if you open your web browser and press **F11**, do you still see the taskbar?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a problem with web browsers, and it only seems to be an issue with some games.

Comment: That being said, it sounds like the most likely culprit would be the offending application's variation of full-screen mode instead of Windows itself.  Hopefully someone else can chime in who has seen similar occurrences on their machine.  On mine, all of the applications that I utilize in full-screen mode (web browsers, VLC player, etc.) work quite well.